# Função AngularJS não está respeitando a condição!

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, laravel

Tenho essa função, que recebe dois parâmetros, porém, quando passo o nome diferente, ele cai no if da mesma maneira.

```
$scope.deleteCategory = function(id, nome)
{

            if(nome == 'Despesas Administrativas' || 'Despesas com Empregados' || 'Despesas Financeiras' || 'Despesas Tributárias' || 'Despesas com Diretoria' || 'Receitas de Serviços' || 'Despesas com Encargos Sociais' || 'Receitas Financeiras')
            {

                        swal("Ops, Não foi possível deletar a categoria "+ nome, "Vocẽ não pode deletar uma categoria padrão!");

                        loadData();   
            }


            else
            {
                $scope.questionMsg('Todas as contas com essa categoria SERÃO EXCLUÍDAS também!')
                    .then(function()
                     {
                        CategoriaService.delete(id, {
                            success: function(response){
                                console.log(response);
                                swal("Salvo!", "Categoria excluida com sucesso", "success");
                                loadData();
                            },

                            error: function(response)
                            {
                                swal("Não foi possível exlcuir", "Tente novamente mais tarde", "error");
                            }
                        });
                        loadData();
                     });
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tem um erro de codificação onde a variável de comparação só estava fazendo a comparação no primeiro e o resto não, para funcionar tem que comparar com todos da seguinte forma:

```
if (nome == 'Despesas Administrativas' || 
   nome == 'Despesas com Empregados' || 
   nome == 'Despesas Financeiras' || 
   nome == 'Despesas Tributárias' || 
   nome == 'Despesas com Diretoria' || 
   nome == 'Receitas de Serviços' || 
   nome == 'Despesas com Encargos Sociais' || 
   nome == 'Receitas Financeiras')
```

se ainda pode melhorar esse código da seguinte forma:

```js
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$haystack = new Array('Despesas Administrativas',
'Despesas com Empregados','Despesas Financeiras',
'Despesas Tributárias', 'Despesas com Diretoria',
'Receitas de Serviços','Despesas com Encargos Sociais',
'Receitas Financeiras');


console.log(inArray('', $haystack)); // false
console.log(inArray('Receitas Financeiras', $haystack)); // true
```

<sub>Referencia:</sub> [JavaScript equivalent of PHP's in_array()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784012/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-in-array)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado!